# Coloring a graph, special case

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question that might be an open problem, I don't know for sure but if you do know the answer please let me know.
Consider a set with $2n$ elements, now consider those subsets of it that have $n$ elements in them. To each subset, assign a graph vertex. Now, connect two vertices if and only if the intersection of their sets have at most one elements in it. I want to show that the "chromatic number" (which I define below) for $n>3$ is equal to 6.
  Chromatic number, by the way, is the least number of colors by which we can paint the vertices such that no two vertices that are adjacent end up with the same color.

What i was looking for appears to be a special case of **generalized kneser graph** (where s=1, which means two vertices are allowed to be connected if their corresponding sets intersect in 1 or 0 elements). I searched some articles yet i could not find a formula for it's chromatic number. again, I want to prove that the chromatic number for $KG_{(2n,n,1)}$ is 6 for n > 3.

Comment: It seems like by color number you mean chromatic number of a graph.

Comment: What is the origin of this question?

Comment: First of all, can you find a 6-coloring for general $n$?

Comment: @Shahab thanks, I didn't know what it was called.

Comment: @CarlHeckman I don't think I can

Comment: @gloomysunday: No problem. I think you will have a better chance of getting someone to answer your question if you add a little more context: from where did you get this question, your graph theory background etc.

Comment: Your graphs are examples of generalized Kneser graphs, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph.

Comment: Here is another reference to such graphs http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009589568790044X

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk Kneser graphs states that two vertices are connected only if their sets are disjoint. in here I said they are allowed to have at most one element in common. so i don't think these two are the same, although they are very similar. in fact what i'm looking for appears to be the generalized kneser graph and chromatic number's formula for this type of graphs.

Comment: This paper may be relevant:  P. FRANKL,. On the chromatic number of the general Kneser-graph, J. Graph Theory 9. (1985), 217-220.

Comment: @Shahab thanks, that's it. but can you tell me one thing based on this article? i read it's abstract and the formula that it has presented. is that an upperbound? or as the author stated it's the exact formula? i mean, is the thing i wanted to prove (chromatic number = 6) wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access the article so I can't give a proper answer. From the abstract I think that the author has given a formula for sufficiently large $n$ and not for all $n$. In any case 6 seems wrong. From where did you assume it was 6?

Comment: gloomysunday: generalized Kneser graphs are described on the same WIKI page as the "standard" Kneser graphs: look better. @Shahab: I think the Frankl article only gives the answer when $n$ and $k$ have a certain relationship. 6 may still be right for the specific case that $n=2k$.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk: For the case $n=2k$ we have the abstract of the above paper saying that the chromatic number tends to $k+3$. That was my reason for doubting the answer is $6$.

Comment: @Shahab: I can only see the abstract, but in the part I see there is the condition that $n>n_0(k)$ is required.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk: Ah yes. I was wrong. It is possible that the answer is 6.

Comment: @Shahab in the article the formula is that for $n>n_0(k)$ the chromatic number is:
$(k-1)Cr(s,2)+rs$ that $n=(k-1)s+r$ and $0 \leq r < k-1$.

Comment: Cr is combinatorial selection. $Cr(s,2)=\cfrac{s!}{(s-2)!2!}$

Comment: @Shahab: I found that indeed the answer is at most 6, so the paper does say nothing about this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial solution, showing that 6 colors are sufficient.

The vertices of our graph $KG_{2n,n,1}$ are the $n$-element subsets of $[2n]$.
We prescribe a coloring for a given subset $A$.

Assign color red if $A$ contains 1 and 2.

Assign color green if $A$ contains neither 1 and 2.

If $A$ contains 1 and not 2, color it blue when it contains 3, and yellow otherwise.

If $A$ contains 2 and not 1, color it white when it contains 3, and black otherwise.

This clearly assigns a color to each subset, and uses exactly 6 colors, so
we only need to show that two vertices with the same color cannot be adjacent.

Two red vertices contain both 1 and 2, so they are not adjacent.
Similarly two blue vertices contain both 1 and 3, two white vertices contain both 2 and 3.

Two green vertices contain neither 1 nor 2, so they must have an intersection of two other elements,
so they are not adjacent.
Similarly two yellow vertices contain neither 2 nor 3, two black vertices contain neither 1 nor 3.

This shows $\chi(KG_{2n,n,1})\leq 6$.

For $n=2$ the graph is simply $K_6$ so 6 colors are required.
For $n=3$ a computer easily shows that 6 colors are required.
I expect that 6 colors are required for all $n$ but have not yet been able to prove it.